# Why doesn't this snippet generate the same standard deviation?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to calculate the std in a non-vectorized and semi-vectorized way. 
the code for non-vectorized version works well, the semi-vectorized version works as well but the results they generate are not the same.
this is the version 1 :

```
import math
#unvectorized version --really slow!
def calc_std_classic(a):
    batch = a.shape[0]
    channel = a.shape[1]
    width = a.shape[2]
    height = a.shape[3]
    mean = calc_mean_classic2(data_train)

    sum = np.zeros((channel))
    for i in range(batch):
        for j in range(channel):
            for w in range(width):
                for h in range(height):
                    sum[j] += (abs(a[i,j,w,h] - mean[j])**2)

    var = (sum/(width*height*batch))
    return [(math.sqrt(x)) for x in var ]
```

semi-vectorized :

```
def calc_std_classic2(a):
    batch = a.shape[0]
    channel = a.shape[1]
    width = a.shape[2]
    height = a.shape[3]
    mean = calc_mean_classic2(data_train)

    sum = np.zeros((channel))
    for i in range(batch):
        for j in range(channel):
            sum[j] += np.sum(abs(a[i,j,:,:] - mean[j])**2)

    var = (sum/(width*height*batch))
    return [(math.sqrt(x)) for x in var ]
```

and this is the method for calculating mean if its needed :

```
def calc_mean_classic2(a):
    #sum all elements in each channel and divide by the number of elements
    batch = a.shape[0]
    channel = a.shape[1]
    width = a.shape[2]
    height = a.shape[3]

    sum = np.zeros((channel))
    for i in range(batch):
        for j in range(channel):
            sum[j] += np.sum(a[i,j,:,:])

    return (sum/(width*height*batch))
```

the output generated using pythons numpy.std() and the two method is as follows:

```
std = np.std(data_train, axis=(0,2,3))
std2 = calc_std_classic(data_train)
std3 = calc_std_classic2(data_train)
```

generates :

```
std = [ 62.99321928  62.08870764  66.70489964]
std2 = [62.99321927774396, 62.08870764038716, 66.7048996406483]
std3 = [62.99321927813685, 62.088707640014405, 66.70489964063101]
```

As you can see, all three generate the same result up to 8 digits. but the 3rd method has different remaining digits.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps numpy uses a more stable sum algorithm.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: is that all? 
Is the procedure I'm doing correct?

Comment: Down vote?!! Why would someone downvote this question?!! whats wrong with it ?

Comment: Well floating point operations are approximative and the "*naive*" sum algorithm can definitely be improved. Some high quality summation algorithms use an additional floating point to store leftovers and add them in the end. I did not downvote btw.

Comment: Thanks alot, so this really boils down to  the summation and nothing else?!
I thought the + operator is used in numpy.sum as well, and nothing else is done thus the result should be the same. by the way is there a way to check the numpy.sum implementation and see what else it is doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of good ressources on floating point arithmetic error propagation. But one immediate problem is that `numpy.ndarray` display floats to a different precision that python `float`s. So to compare your results you should convert to an identical data structure (for example `list`s):

```
>>> print(np.std(arr, ....))
[ 0.28921072  0.2898092   0.28961785]
>>> print(np.std(arr, ....).tolist())
[0.28921072085015914, 0.28980920065339233, 0.28961784922639483]
```

---

In your explicit case:

The difference between `calc_std_classic` and `calc_std_classic2` is because one uses naive summation `a1+a2+....+an` while the other uses `np.sum`. The `np.sum` could be naive summation but as far as I know it uses [*pairwise summation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation). If you want even higher accuracy you could implement [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) or use the python-builtin [`statistics._sum`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/403ccddb9598bac6e0e6db4ba5aa2fe494512a98/Lib/statistics.py#L106).

The difference between `np.std` and your variants is harder to explain because I don't know what algorithm is used by `numpy`. There is a whole [article about "Algorithms for calculating variance" on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance). Note that any naive implementation may suffer from under-/overflow issues especially because of the `item - mean` subtraction.

---

A general advice:

If you want it fast then use `numpy`, if you want it with highest precision then use [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html). NumPy mostly focusses on the performance aspect so they *might not* implement the most accurate algorithm. Avoid any naive implementations without doing research on the algorithm, because they probably are neither accurate nor fast.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your nice answer :)